# Basic skills that should be learnt before playing ranked

Tags: league-of-legends

I am a beginner in league of legends and what I would like to know is are there certain skills that should be learnt before playing PVP (Ranked or Normals) like kiting etc.

It would be helpful if anyone could name those skills and briefly describe them.

Comment: csing, that's probably all you need to get out of low bronze.

Comment: Other skills are likely going to be dependant on what role (and even maybe champion) you play. For instance kiting/positining is going to be more important for an adc than for a tank.

Comment: Also just a suggestion, maybe you could upload a replay of one of your games and ask people to review it so that they could point out which of these basic skills you are most lacking in at your current skill level.

Comment: Also, in addition to what @Aequitas said, it's dependant on what role you intend to play. So say you mainly want to play as tank, then proper engaging and focusing may be more important than playing an ADC where your main duty is to stay alive and deal damage. Please describe more of your personal style, e.g. Champions most-liked, favourite roles etc.

Comment: @Aequitas You need to play (mostly) carry aswell, you can't rely on others winning the game for you if you want to ladder, otherwise you will just end up with a 50% winrate and stall at your rank, cause team mates are luck (coin toss, basically, so fair luck).

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I disagree. There are too many people who think they must carry the game. You don't have to, it's important to know when and how to let your teammates carry. As long as you have a positive impact on the game you'll have more than 50% and thus climb. Obviously it's not as effective as carrying since you have less of an impact.

Comment: [A Guide to Playing League of Legends Ranked Games](http://passthejelly.hubpages.com/hub/aguidetoplayinglol)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kiting](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2067024&page=1#post23715190) is a (kind of) advanced skill, that you're not going to need at the beginning of your ladder-climbing journey.

However, here's a (non-exhaustive) list of things you wanna consider if you want to improve on League of Legends. Those items does not only concern people that start playing ranked games, it is also interesting for anyone who want to improve on the game, at any level.

## 1. Play champions and roles you're the best with

That may be obvious, but ranked games are not a place where you want to try the new champion, or test whether the new OP Xin Zhao build is really OP or not (and you've never played this champion before !). You should pick the champion and/or role you're best with. **Implicitly**, you know better the damage you deal all along the game, you know the strength, the speed, the power spikes, etc. This has a huge impact on helping you winning your lane, and therefore winning your games.

In League of Legends, success is highly related to knowledge and *mechanical skill* won't help you if you do not have a minimum understanding of every champion. **Your general knowledge about the game and your champion pool will grow by the time you play**. Keep on practicing!

## 2. Know how to CS properly

As @Aequitas mentioned, this is the bread-and-butter for anyone who wants to improve. It gives you so much free gold, it's just up to you to pick it up the best you can.

- If you just start playing ranked games, you want to *mechanically* farm correctly, that is to say *last-hitting*. Launch games in training mode, with or without bots, and try to miss as few last-hits as possible. When playing ranked games, having 150 cs at 20 minutes is considered (in average) a good farming. Try to aim for that in your own games.
- In a higher level, last hitting is not the main reason why people reach 200 cs at 20 minutes. More experienced players should learn how to **control wave**. I won't detail here how to [freeze](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=28513914), [push](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1469083), [slow-push](https://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/1gbxx6/what_minion_setup_do_you_have_to_create_to/), and [recall](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/tips-tricks/UGEQxI3j-when-do-you-recall) effectively.

## 3. Ward and watch your minimap

You may think that carrying your games is way more important that vision or anything. But vision not only brings you clarity on the game, it also gives information on where the pressure is on the map.

When you start playing ranked games, you die a lot. And most of your deaths are caused by *lack of vision.* Ward your lane and enemy jungle if you can, and **don't forget to watch the minimap** (that's what warding is for).

Try to watch the minimap as much as you can. A good exercise is forcing yourself to **watch the minimap between every CS**. This might sound too much but it's not ! This is super important that you're able to spot the location of every opponent on the map (watching it very often prevents you from ganks).

## 4. Don't get discouraged, keep on thinking positive, recognize your mistakes !

Every player makes mistakes. Every player. So are you, and it's always good to know when you've done some. Watch replays, spot the errors that you don't want to do again, and you'll improve.

Do not "tilt". It's useless. It **will** make you lose games. Be aware of what your teammates do or say ; mute "flamers" and focus on your game. If you get killed early or if you're having a bad game, don't lose hope and try the best you can. Never surrender or `/ff` during your ranked games !

---

Of course this list is not complete. **I encourage everyone of you who has additional info/advice to put it here.**

Comment: 1 is a good point, to expand on it a bit more I'd say learn all/most of the champions. Just like have a basic understanding of what each one can do, try and play a game with all the champs you haven't yet played (wait for them to be on the free rotation). If you're against someone who you don't know what their skills are, quickly look it up online during loading screen and before minions spawn.

Comment: Some more things: Dont think twice about muting the flamers, they never change. Turn off your all-chat, it's irrelevant for your game and only distracts you. Stay away from advanced tactics (countering meta picks, psychological mindgames, ..) until you are fluent with the basics. As @Aequitas said, knowledge is power; (rudimentarily) know what each champ brings to the table so you know what to expect.

Comment: I think 4 is a crucial point for any PVP gamer.  Especially recognizing mistakes.  My rule of thumb is _there is always something you could have done better_.  If you analyze any situation after the fact, you can usually see what mistakes were detrimental.  This is true even when you are successful.  I find it especially important to avoid putting the blame on others.  You will never have control on how your teammates play, but you will always have control of your own play, so that should be every players focus.

Answer (score 6):

- Behave like an adult in **any** situation
- Do not be toxic, under any circumstances
- always play as team and act like a team player
- Do not flame or insult other players (both teams)
- Do not leave the game or go AFK, always think about having enough time to play a game BEFORE you start it
- Comeback is always possible

If you master these rules, you will be way more successful than being able to kite or anything else

Comment: These are not skills. Just common sense.

Comment: aprox. 95% of players do not have this.

Comment: @Artery Agreed. It's hard to believe how often I've started a ranked match and then my randomized teammates start chatting inappropriate/sexual/racist comments ticking off or tilting people.